# KeyListener and boolean not working

Tags: java, boolean, awt, keylistener, awtrobot

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {
    static boolean check = false;
    static boolean boom = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        do{
        if(check == true){
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.delay(1000);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        }
        }while(boom == true);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_F9){
            check = true;
            boom = true;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_F11){
            check = false;
            boom = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code,I want it work like this:
When you press F9 it should start write .menu and when pressing F11 it should stop.
Any Help?

Comment: You have a `keyPressed` function, is this part of a `KeyListener` classs? If so what is it attached to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've no GUI component visible for the KeyListener to listen to. KeyListeners require that they be added to a component within a rendered GUI and the component being listened to has focus. Your app has none of that. I don't even see a KeyListener object anywhere within your code.

If you want to create a GUI that listens for key events, consider learning how to create a Java Swing GUI at the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), and then consider using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) in place of a low-level listener such as a KeyListener.

If on the other hand you wish to create a general key logger program without a GUI, then I suggest you not use Java but instead some other language that allows tighter integration with the operating system.